# Why do my objects have white dots on them?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

What are these dots and how can I remove them?

[image]

I am using version 2.79b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those little white dots are called fireflies. 
They are an annoying side effect of rendering. The easiest way to remove them is to just increase the sample count.

Blender Guru also has an article about how to get rid of them. https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies