# How to get rid of fireflies in blender 2.8 mesh

Tags: 3d-view

When I use image reference in Blender 2.8 viewport, I'm getting these fireflies
[image: in the mesh]

I read [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115051/why-do-my-objects-have-white-dots-on-them?newreg=8a09416d9e254c26a9c4ed1d4308eec4) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussions, but here it's happening in the mesh, not on the rendered image. It doesn't happen if I remove image reference.

Any idea how to get rid of this?